# External API Calling Security

Tags: chainlink

If I'm calling an external API from a smart contract, how safe and secure can I assume the data come back is?  What is in place to prevent a rogue node from doing bad things?  Is a 51% attack a thing that could cause bad data posted to the contract, resulting in a potential exploit?  I understand that the api is called and the results are added to to the block chain, but what security is in place to make sure that it's as decentralized as possible and the data from the API is what is actually put on chain?

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink services that run the Offchain Reporting Protocol have consensus mechanisms that are documented [here](https://research.chain.link/ocr.pdf). The [official docs](https://docs.chain.link/architecture-overview/off-chain-reporting#:%7E:text=The%20OCR%20protocol%20allows%20nodes,by%20a%20quorum%20of%20nodes.) also explain this.